# Is it possible to set a header based on the UAGENT in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

Because microsoft internet explorer and microsoft edge don't support content security policy version 2 or, in case of IE, don't support it at all I would like to change the content security policy based on the user agent. This is fairly simple with PHP but I would like to do this with .htaccess file. The question is; is this possible and how. So far I found lots of rewrite rules but no mod_headers doing this.

Searching for something like this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: ...

<UserAgentMatch "(Edge|Internet Explorer)$">
   Header unset Content-Security-Policy
</UserAgentMatch>
```

Anyone have an idea how I can do this and if its possible?

**UPDATE:**

The answer of Walf gives an internal server error but after some finetuning resulted in a solution. For those looking for the same see code below.

```
 <If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /(MSIE|Edge)s*/i">
   header always set Content-Security-Policy "..." 
 </If>
```

Comment: Your regex is still wrong, you've lost the space before the keywords and you're looking for a literal `s`, i.e. it will match the word `Wedges`. Did you try double-escaping the backslashes, since they're in a quoted string? Try `<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /\\s+(?:MSIE\\s+\\d|Edge\\/)/">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried setting the header only if it's *not* those browsers?

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /\s+(?:MSIE\s+\d|Edge\/)/">
    Content-Security-Policy: ... 
</If>
```